# How to create a grid of splitters

Tags: python, pyqt, qgridlayout, qsplitter

What I'm trying to do is add splitter to a QGridLayout in order to resize the layout with the mouse. So for instance with this :

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.setFixedHeight(100)

        self.wid = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.wid)

        self.grid = QGridLayout()

        l_a = QLabel('A')
        l_b = QLabel('B')
        l_c = QLabel('C')
        l_d = QLabel('D')
        l_e = QLabel('E')
        l_f = QLabel('F')
        l_g = QLabel('G')
        l_h = QLabel('H')
        l_i = QLabel('I')
        self.grid.addWidget(l_a, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(l_b, 0, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(l_c, 0, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(l_d, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(l_e, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(l_f, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(l_g, 2, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(l_h, 2, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(l_i, 2, 2)
        self.wid.setLayout(self.grid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('window')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

I get this:

[image]

What I would like is instead of the colored line, have the possibility to click and drag vertically (for green lines) and horizontally (for red lines) the grid borders.

I tried something with QSplitter directly, but I end up with:

[image]

The Horizontal splits are okay, but the vertical ones are not aligned any more:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.setFixedHeight(100)

        self.wid = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.wid)

        # self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.globallayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.split_V = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)

        l_a = QLabel('A')
        l_b = QLabel('B')
        l_c = QLabel('C')
        l_d = QLabel('D')
        l_e = QLabel('E')
        l_f = QLabel('F')
        l_g = QLabel('G')
        l_h = QLabel('H')
        l_i = QLabel('I')
        split_H = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        split_H.addWidget(l_a)
        split_H.addWidget(l_b)
        split_H.addWidget(l_c)
        self.split_V.addWidget(split_H)

        split_H = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        split_H.addWidget(l_d)
        split_H.addWidget(l_e)
        split_H.addWidget(l_f)
        self.split_V.addWidget(split_H)

        split_H = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        split_H.addWidget(l_g)
        split_H.addWidget(l_h)
        split_H.addWidget(l_i)
        self.split_V.addWidget(split_H)

        self.globallayout.addWidget(self.split_V)

        self.wid.setLayout(self.globallayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('window')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

### Update

I think I almost found a solution where a function is used so that whenever the vertical splits are changed, it re-aligns them:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.setFixedHeight(100)

        self.wid = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.wid)

        # self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.globallayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.split_V = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)

        l_a = QLabel('A')
        l_b = QLabel('B')
        l_c = QLabel('C')
        l_d = QLabel('D')
        l_e = QLabel('E')
        l_f = QLabel('F')
        l_g = QLabel('G')
        l_h = QLabel('H')
        l_i = QLabel('I')
        self.split_H1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.split_H1.addWidget(l_a)
        self.split_H1.addWidget(l_b)
        self.split_H1.addWidget(l_c)
        self.split_V.addWidget(self.split_H1)

        self.split_H2 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.split_H2.addWidget(l_d)
        self.split_H2.addWidget(l_e)
        self.split_H2.addWidget(l_f)
        self.split_V.addWidget(self.split_H2)

        self.split_H3 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.split_H3.addWidget(l_g)
        self.split_H3.addWidget(l_h)
        self.split_H3.addWidget(l_i)
        self.split_V.addWidget(self.split_H3)

        self.globallayout.addWidget(self.split_V)

        self.wid.setLayout(self.globallayout)

        self.split_H1.splitterMoved.connect(self.moveSplitter)
        self.split_H2.splitterMoved.connect(self.moveSplitter)
        self.split_H3.splitterMoved.connect(self.moveSplitter)

        # self.split_H1.splitterMoved
        # self.moveSplitter(0,self.split_H1.at )

    def moveSplitter( self, index, pos ):
        # splt = self._spltA if self.sender() == self._spltB else self._spltB
        self.split_H1.blockSignals(True)
        self.split_H2.blockSignals(True)
        self.split_H3.blockSignals(True)
        self.split_H1.moveSplitter(index, pos)
        self.split_H2.moveSplitter(index, pos)
        self.split_H3.moveSplitter(index, pos)
        self.split_H1.blockSignals(False)
        self.split_H2.blockSignals(False)
        self.split_H3.blockSignals(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('window')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

However, I still have an issue at the begining - the alignment is not correct :

[image]

I don't know How call the function `moveSplitter` in the `__init__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that directly calling `moveSplitter` (which is a protected method) may be problematic. Using Qt-5.10.1 with PyQt-5.10.1 on Linux, I found that it can often result in a core dump when called during `__init__`. There is probably a good reason why Qt provides `setSizes` as a public method for changing the position of the splitters, so it may be wise to prefer it over `moveSplitter`.

With that in mind, I arrived at the following implementation:

```
class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.split_H1.splitterMoved.connect(self.moveSplitter)
        self.split_H2.splitterMoved.connect(self.moveSplitter)
        self.split_H3.splitterMoved.connect(self.moveSplitter)

        QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.split_H1.splitterMoved.emit(0, 0))

    def moveSplitter(self, index, pos):
        sizes = self.sender().sizes()
        for index in range(self.split_V.count()):
            self.split_V.widget(index).setSizes(sizes)
```

The single-shot timer is needed because on some platforms the geometry of the window may not be fully initialized before it is shown on screen. And note that `setSizes` does not trigger `splitterMoved`, so there is no need to block signals when using it.

Comment: That is not working, the two last columns are out of screen (to the right).
Instead of calling `self.moveSplitter`, I call `self.split_H1.setSizes([100000,100000,100000])`, 
        `self.split_H2.setSizes([100000,100000,100000])`, 
        `self.split_H3.setSizes([100000,100000,100000])`. That's working. However, I should use sys.maxsize to get the int max value but if I do so, I get a weird message: TypeError: index 0 has type 'int' but 'int' is expected

Comment: @ymmx. Weird. Yesterday it worked perfectly, and now it's producing all sorts of problems. I have therefore completely revised my answer and provided an alternative solution. It works fine for me on linux, but I have not tested it on other platforms. You may need to add a small delay to the timer to get it to work properly on all systems.

Comment: That works on Windows. To be honest, your answer is clearly beyond my Qt comprehension, but it works so I take it :) Thks